# Filtering on ANY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
studentID subjectID PASS
101        1         T
102        1         F
101        2         F
101        3         T
102        2         F
```

I should raise an alert `if a student has not passed in ALL of the subjects he had attempted.`

So,in the above case - `the query should return only 102.`

`Note - it should also not return 103,who has not attempted any of the subjects(assuming we are joining this with the student table).`

Comment: Why would it return 103 if it isn't in the table to begin with?

Comment: Either I'm misinterpreting the question (which is possible) or your data doesn't match up with what you're saying should happen. Both 101 and 102 have failed to pass a subject in your sample data set; why exactly should only 102 be returned by the query?

Comment: a student should be returned only if he failed in ALL the subjects attempted

Comment: @IUnknown Ok, it's a case of ambiguous wording in the question then. When I read that, a student who has not passed in all of their subjects is somebody who has failed at least one subject (but may have passed others). I'd suggest editing the question to make that clear by explicitly saying failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of such students by doing:

```
select studentId
from table t
group by studentId
having max(PASS) = 0;
```

How you raise the alert is another matter.  You should probably schedule a job to do that.

EDIT:

Well, the definition of `PASS` changed since my original answer.  Here is a revision for a character field:

```
select studentId
from table t
group by studentId
having sum(case when PASS = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: PASS is nto a numeric field  - something i should have taken care of when thinking of the example.

Comment: may be you should consider reviewing your answer?

Comment: Just because it's text rather than numeric doesn't mean that you can't use the first simple form - `T` sorts later than `F`, so `MAX(PASS)='F'` should work.

Answer (score 0):

*List studentid having failed in all subjects attended*?

Try this!

```
;with cte as
(
select studentID, case when pass='T' then 1 else 0 end as xx from #t
)
select studentID from cte  group by studentID having sum(xx)=0
```

or without `CTE`

```
select studentID from 
(
select studentID, case when pass='T' then 1 else 0 end as xx from #t
)x
group by studentID having sum(xx)=0
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/19172)